# Apache ignite - querying on partitioned cache data count results in query execution on every node and gives more rows than 1

Tags: ignite

apache ignite: 1.7
I have 
5 ignite nodes 
with cacheMode as partitioned 
and on the same server.
with each node having data for a single table from the data source.

The cache name is the same in all nodes, not sure if that makes any difference.
After loading data into cache, 
if i try to query the cache data just to get a count of rows loaded,
using jdbc url
**jdbc:ignite://localhost:11211/cacheName**
**I see that count appears five times for the below query.**
Select count(1) from cacheName.ObjectName
I was expecting only 1 count though as i am executing it only once and the result set should have returned only 1 row,
could you point what am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Does `select count(*) from ObjectName` works? Can you show your cache configuration and code that loads the data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. Here s the cache config <property name="cacheConfiguration">
   <list>
    <bean id="cacheCfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
     <property name="startSize" value="#{500 * 1024 * 1024}" />
     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
     <property name="memoryMode" value="ONHEAP_TIERED" />
     <property name="backups" value="1"></property>
     <property name="cacheStoreFactory" ref="jdbcFactory" />
     <property name="queryEntities">
     <list>...</list>
     </property>

Comment: Here s the code sample that loads data. IgniteCache<Long, Object> gpDataCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("gpDataCache");
   
   gpDataCache.loadCache(null, Table1Key.class.getName(),"Select f.* from xx.table1"); Similarly loading 5 tables in 5 nodes

Comment: What does `gpDataCache.size()` return? How many entries do you expect? Please also provide the code using https://gist.github.com/ or similar service. It's not readable here.